# What is the Windows Store app equivalent of the StatusBar in Windows Store Phone Apps called?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8

There's a bar at the top of Windows Store Phone Apps called a StatusBar, accessible in code @ Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar. It's helpfully labelled in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn596110.aspx) introduction to Windows Phone Store Apps.

Then there's a bar at the top of Windows Store Apps (that is, the ones you run on a desktop PC) which only shows up when you hover your mouse near the top of the screen. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLkp2.jpg) is a picture of it, it's a black bar at the very top of the image.

What is that black bar called? And where is the component stored in the Windows.UI library? I'm looking for some equivalent of Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar, and I've had no luck at all trying to find it in documentation since I don't know what it's called.

Comment: You mean the status bar for a Win Store app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the Title bar and it is a part of Windows since maybe the first version, it is not Metro specific. It was added to Metro apps in 8.1 to make it easier for the users to close the apps. You cannot access it from code, there is no API.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 8.1 and below, there's no such API.

However, Windows 10 will introduce an API for the title bar, [as described and explored](http://blog.thomasnigro.fr/2015/02/11/exploring-w10-apis-windows-and-titlebar/). Tweetium and VLC already feature this in their apps.

From the site above, here's some code which you can already use, although the W10 APIs are not yet released:

```
var v = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
var allProperties = v.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
var titleBar = allProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "TitleBar");
if (titleBar == null) return;
dynamic titleBarInst = titleBar.GetMethod.Invoke(v, null);
titleBarInst.BackgroundColor = Colors.CornflowerBlue;
titleBarInst.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
titleBarInst.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.DimGray;
titleBarInst.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Orange;
```

So with Win 10 APIs (not yet released!) the following code should be possible:

```
var v = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();        
v.TitleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.CornflowerBlue;
v.TitleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
v.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.DimGray;
v.TitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Orange;
```